# Word for earning less than spent

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

The word could be any part of speech. The purpose is to communicate that an entity was gaining less than losing. Income < expenses.

Example 1:

> The company has been _________ for the last 2 years.

Example 2:

> He has been working ______ for the last few months.

Comment: I think you question is unclear. You are referring to different concepts. Being unprofitable has little to do with spending more than one is gaining. I suggest you refer to the economics site. https://economics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @user5768790 I agree. The question in the title doesn't match the question in the body. So, my suggestion is: *not make (both) ends meet*.

Comment: you would likely use a different word/phrase for the two different examples.  Companies operate "in the red/in the black" whereas a you would rarely refer to a person as operating "in the red".  I would rephrase the second example to:
"He's been spending more than his income the last few months"

Answer (score 38, accepted):

A common expression for this would be (operating) ***[at a loss](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/at_a_loss)***:

> Making less money than is spent buying, operating, or producing something.
>   *‘a railway running at a loss’*
>   *<sub>definition from [oxford dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/at_a_loss)</sub>*

Answer (score 27):

I would say that the company has been **in the red**:

> The expression "in the red" generally is used to describe a business that is operating at a loss.
>   <sub>[What Does It Mean When a Company Is in the Red?](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/mean-company-red-80389.html)</sub>

This expression can also be applied to individuals, but it is most often used with businesses.

---

Another option is simply **in debt**.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74446/discussion-on-answer-by-laurel-word-for-earning-less-than-spent).

Answer (score 18):

For people, you could say they are "living beyond their means". According to Collins English Dictionary

> If someone is living beyond their means, they are spending more money than they can afford.

This isn’t used so much for companies, but you could say they are "making a loss".

Answer (score 10):

I would suggest '**unprofitable**' since the whole idea of being in business or being in employment is to make a profit.

> not profitable : producing **no gain**, good, or result an unprofitable venture

[Merriam Webter](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unprofitable)

> Welsh Dairy: New Report Shows Up To 75% Of Farms Are **Unprofitable**

[PlantBased](https://www.plantbasednews.org/post/some-dairy-farms-have-never-made-a-profit)

Comment: Sometimes *lossmaking* or (in OPs second example) *at a loss*.

Comment: That is a good one! Can you come up with any verb that denotes the similar meaning?

Comment: @Eduard 'Non-profitmaking' ?

Answer (score 9):

The phrase **deficit spending** is commonly said of governments when it does that.  I know many people who slightly bend that to be humorous when an individual does that.

> Bernie has embraced fiscal excess in the form of *deficit spending* at the pubs lately.

Comment: "running a deficit" would be the phrase to insert in the OP's sentence

Answer (score 7):

> [**in the red**](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/in-the-red.html) ~ A slang phrase referring to a company that is burdened by operating expenses and is unable to generate revenue.
> *<sub>from [businessdictionary.com](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/in-the-red.html)</sub>*

- The company has been **in the red** for the last 2 years.
- He has been working **in the red** for the last few months.

> *phrase* ~ If a person or company is [**in the red**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/in-the-red) or if their bank account is [**in the red**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/in-the-red), they have spent more money than they have in their account and therefore they owe money to the bank.
> *<sub>from [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/in-the-red)</sub>*

This commonly used idiom is based on the historically traditional book-keeping practice of using [*red ink*](https://books.google.com/books?id=KR1LAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA53&lpg=PA53&dq=bookkeeper%20used%20red%20ink&source=bl&ots=6HqjnLLE7I&sig=LW_m5pHE2XEnSRyZOJYykY2a31Y&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIvt3vluXZAhVMVWMKHTiiA2QQ6AEIZDAC#v=onepage&q=bookkeeper%20used%20red%20ink&f=false) for outstanding balances in ledgers. From what I gather, the practice was rather informal or optional (depending on company or individual preferences), although often used by old-fashioned book-keepers who entered all information into their ledgers *by hand*. Many of them kept pens of different colored inks, each of which had a specific symbolic meaning. [Red ink](https://books.google.com/books?id=KR1LAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA53&lpg=PA53&dq=bookkeeper%20used%20red%20ink&source=bl&ots=6HqjnLLE7I&sig=LW_m5pHE2XEnSRyZOJYykY2a31Y&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIvt3vluXZAhVMVWMKHTiiA2QQ6AEIZDAC#v=onepage&q=bookkeeper%20used%20red%20ink&f=false) could mean almost anything, depending on how it was implemented, but *relevant to this particular popular idiom, it meant* ***money owed***.

> [**in the red**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+red) in debt, overdrawn, or losing money.
> Red ink was traditionally used to indicate debit items and balances in accounts. Compare with [in the black](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+black)
> *<sub>from [freedictionary.com](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+red)</sub>*

Answer (score 1):

A less common word that might apply is [*impecunious*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impecunious). The strict definition means someone (or an entity) with no money or assets, but I've often heard it used to mean someone who is not good at managing their money.

Answer (score 1):

The following might do: [*to overspend* in Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/overspend), even though it does not explicitly touch on *income*, but rather on what one could afford:

> If you overspend, you spend more money than you can afford to.

So we get:

> The company has been **overspending** for the last 2 years.

Answer (score 0):

[burn the candle at both ends](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/burn-the-candle-at-both-ends) - idiom (informal) meaning to work long hours without rest.

```
 You'll wear yourself out if you keep **burning the candle at both ends**.
```

[unsustainably](https://www.google.ca/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/unsustainably) - adv. in a way that cannot continue over a period of time:

**adv** + adj

Prices have been set **unsustainably** high for years.

Search results for v + **adv** offer only results for the affirmative sustainably.

[Ten Ways to Live Sustainably](http://www.dummies.com/education/science/environmental-science/ten-ways-to-live-sustainably/) (book title)

Seeing how the word **unsustainably** exists, would going from the collocation "live sustainably" to "work unsustainably" be too big of a stretch?

Comment: add citations for your choices and defend them with elaboration.

Answer (score 0):

For an individual, a common way of saying it is, "living beyond his means".  Depending on how formal the language of the document is, for a company you could say, "spending beyond its means" or "spending beyond their means".